# angular4 - click function on the div

Tags: angular, click

I want to see only div-2 after the page load, then after I click `div-2`, I want to hide `div-2` and show `div-1`.

```
<div class="div-1"><p>content 1</p></div>
<div class="div-2" (click)="on = true"><p>content 2</p></div>
```

Comment: Do you know about the directive ngIf?

Comment: yes , ill try it, but not working

Comment: Provide your code with a directive, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your component `ts` file you need to have a flag to show and hide the div as follows:

ts:

```
// set to true as we want to show div-2 at first 
public showDiv2: boolean = true;
```

In `html` we will use the flag `showDiv2` to hide and show both the div's:

html:

```
<div class="div-1" *ngIf="!showDiv2"><p>content 1</p></div>
<div class="div-2" *ngIf="showDiv2" (click)="showDiv2 = false"><p>content 2</p></div>
```

You can read more about `ngIf` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)